# How to deal with ViewController in view of other ViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access, popover

I'll try to make own popover (on iPhone, iOS6) and I need to show `ViewController` in subview of other `ViewController`. It's ok - I created `ViewController` class with `XIB` interface and added one button and connected action which return some `NSLog`. I load this `ViewController` as follow:

```
PopoverViewController *popover = [[PopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopoverViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:popover.view];
```

It's working - `view` from `PopoverViewController` is visible on `ViewController`, but when I clicked button which is subview of `PopoverViewController` then I've got `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in line:

```
0x3968a5b0:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]
```

How to deal with it, and how to show second view controller correctly?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Most likely the `popover` view controller is being deallocated because you don't keep a reference to it anywhere.

Comment: What is the button's action? Chances are you've connected it to a nonexistent action.

Comment: I'm using ARC and action exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ARC and you don't keep a strong reference to the `PopoverViewController`, then the view controller will be deallocated even though you add its view to another view. Then when you tap a button in the popover's view, the button's target is gone and the app crashes.

Either add an instance variable to keep a reference to the `PopoverViewController` or better yet, update your view controller's code to properly be a container view controller. You really shouldn't just add one view controller's view to another view controller's view. See the docs for `UIViewController` for the proper way to create a container view controller.

Comment: I declared object of `PopoverViewController` class in `ViewController` interface and it's working now.